# The Lebesgue Integeral of $f(x) = \operatorname{int}(x^{2})$ over $[0,2]$ (integer part)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I just finished working on this Lebesgue integration problem and I am having doubts regarding my work. Note that I will use the notation $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ to denote the Lebesgue integral in this problem.

$ex$: Find the Lebesgue integral of $f$ over $E$ where $f(x) := \operatorname{int}(x^{2})$ and $E = [0,2]$. Note that $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\operatorname{int}$ is the integer part of the real number.

Here is my work:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2}\operatorname{int}(x^{2})dx &= 0m([0,1])+1m([1,\sqrt2)]+4m([\sqrt2,\sqrt3]) \\
 &= \sqrt2 - 1 +4\sqrt3-4\sqrt2.  \\
\end{align*}$$

For some reason in my textbook, the solution has the integral going from $0$ to $4$ so i'm not sure if this is correct or not (since the textbook solution looks wrong).

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: I guess int is the integer part (round towards zero)? If so, you missed the contribution from $[\sqrt{3},2]$ and also the integer part of $x^2$ on $[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ will just be $2$ not $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2}\operatorname{int}(x^{2})dx &= 0m([0,1])+1m([1,\sqrt2)]+2m([\sqrt2,\sqrt3]) \\ +3(2-\sqrt 3)
 &= \sqrt2 - 1 +2\sqrt3-2\sqrt2+3(2-\sqrt 3).  \\
\end{align*}$$ Integer part of $x^{2}$ when $x$ is between $\sqrt 2 $ and $\sqrt 3$ is $2$, not $4$. (This should agree with the answer in the bbok (which uses susbtitution to evalute the integral).

Comment: You also missed the part on $[\sqrt{3},2]$ :)

Comment: Shouldn't there be an interval $[\sqrt{3},2)?$

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. You have helped me a few times now with my questions in measure theory! Much appreciated.